# List view load specific amounts at a time

Tags: android, facebook, listview, android-fragments

My listview has 634 items, but i would like to load them in groups of 15 when user scrolls down it loads more.

Im using a fragment and a listview and not listview fragment.

Code snippet to get facebook friends (634 in my case)

```
 public void getFriends(Session session)
    {
        Request friendsRequest = createRequest(session);

        friendsRequest.setCallback(new Request.Callback(){

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response)
            {
                Log.v(TAG, "completed");
                i=new ArrayList<InvitesModel>();
                for(GraphUser g:installedUsers(getResults(response)))
                {
                    InvitesModel invitesModel=new InvitesModel();
                    invitesModel.setFname(g.getFirstName());
                    invitesModel.setLname(g.getLastName());
                    invitesModel.setId(g.getId());
                    i.add(invitesModel);
                    Collections.sort(i,new Comparator<InvitesModel>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(InvitesModel invitesModel, InvitesModel invitesModel2) {
                            InvitesModel i1= invitesModel;
                            InvitesModel i2=invitesModel2;
                            return (i1.getFname()+" "+i1.getLname()).compareToIgnoreCase(i2.getFname()+" "+i2.getLname());
                        }
                    });
                }
                InvitesAdapter invitesAdapter=invitesAdapter=new InvitesAdapter(getActivity(),i);
                for(InvitesModel invites:i)
                {
                invitesAdapter.add(invites);
                }
                Log.v(TAG,"fb friends"+i.size());
                lv.setAdapter(invitesAdapter);
                Log.v(TAG,"list size"+lv.getCount());
                Log.v(TAG,"adapter size"+invitesAdapter.getCount());
            }
        });

        friendsRequest.executeAsync();
    }
```

My Adapter

```
public class InvitesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<InvitesModel> {

    private final Context context;
    private final List<InvitesModel> user;
    private String TAG="InvitesAdapter";

    public InvitesAdapter(Context context,List<InvitesModel>users) {
        super(context, R.layout.invites_row);
        this.context = context;
        this.user=users;
        Log.v(TAG,"AdapterCalled");
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected RobotoLight text;
        protected RoundedImageView pic;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.invites_row, null);
            viewHolder.text = (RobotoLight) convertView.findViewById(R.id.invites_row_name);
            viewHolder.pic=(RoundedImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.invites_row_pic);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else
        {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        try
        {
            UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(viewHolder.pic, "http://graph.facebook.com/" + user.get(position).getId() + "/picture?width=200&height=200", R.drawable.profle);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
            viewHolder.pic.setImageResource(R.drawable.profle);
        }

        viewHolder.text.setText(user.get(position).getFname()+" "+user.get(position).getLname());

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: if user see only 15 items on the screen at a time, then why you want to load 30 items at a time.

Comment: changed the original post to 15.

Comment: Hi,number does not matter . listview load only those number of items that are visible on the screen,it may varies from device to device.but when you scroll up the list ,then it creates next items for you. but you can manage the efficiency of the listview please find the link.http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html     and mark the answer acceptable if it helps you.

Comment: Thanks ashish  for pointing me in the right direction but im getting 67 Frames skipped Choreographer error. UI Thread doing too much work.

Comment: any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you are loading the images via http and android recommend to perform http operation via async task. UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(viewHolder.pic, "http://graph.facebook.com/" + user.get(position).getId() + "/picture?width=200&height=200", R.drawable.profle);

Comment: UrlImageViewHelper is an async lib, but im gonna wrap in in an async task and see what happens.